# HTML Form as link is corrupting the adress

Tags: html, forms

i assume this is a noob question, so sorry.
I'm trying to write this HTML-Page with a "form" that will work like a link on my raspberry pi.

So I  used this code:

```
<form action="http://192.168.178.62/graph.pl?type=week">
    <input type="submit" value="Blah" />
</form>
```

But instead of ending up at the adress I wrote in the code, I end up here:  http://192.168.178.62/graph.pl? ("type=week" is missing, its just cut off)
Why is that, and how can I fix it?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form with `method="GET"` (which is the default) then a new query string will be generated from the `name`s and `value`s of the successful form controls (since you don't have any, it will be empty). The new (empty) query string will replace the one in the `action`.

Options:

- Use a link. (This is the best option. You aren't collecting any data from the user. You aren't making a POST request).
- Move the data from the `action` to `<input type="hidden" ...>` elements.